# How to add a data quality check utility in awe glue.?

Tags: validation, aws-glue, data-quality

How to add a job that just checks for data quality like null, correct data type etc in aws glue

Answer (score 1):

you can check pyDeequ library too. It enables you to implement python code to DQ checks.

Answer (score -1):

You can write pyspark glue job for quality check.
You can also use [AWS Deequ](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ) library to do it but it is in scala.